# Get string value from http response with Mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I'm currently integrating facebook into my current app and I've succeeded in retrieving the access_token using the following code:

```
url = "#{url}?#{client_id}&#{client_secret}&#{code}&#{redirect_uri}&type=client_cred"

agent = Mechanize.new

page = agent.get(url)
```

The page object above has a body which contains text something along the lines of

```
access_token=XXXXX
```

I just want to pull out the access_token value. I can get the entire string simply by writing:

```
page.body
```

But I was wondering is there a way to get the access_token value without resorting to regular expressions etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the best way I could find to do this was:

token = page.body.split(/access_token=/)[1]